# change static url to dynamic with mod_rewrite

Tags: regex, mod-rewrite

I need to change something like this:

```
www.mydomain.com/www.otherdomain.com
```

to this:

```
www.mydomain.com/index.php?co=www.otherdomain.com
```

Using mod_rewrite I came up with this:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*.)+$ index.php?co=$1 [L]
```

However it is only returning "index.php" for the `co` parameter and not "www.otherdomain.com" like I want it to.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index\.php
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?co=$1
```

The RewriteCond checks that the requested path does not already begin with "/index.php" (without this check an infinite loop will occur). And, if not, the RewriteRule then rewrites everything in the request to the index.php path you need.